# vacation or time off calendar

Tags: php, javascript, calendar

I would like to display vacation and time offs on a linear calendar where the days of the months are the column names and rows are the employee names. 
I know there is a way to achieve this using php and javascript but I would like to know if there is a shortcut solution that I can use to implement this quicker.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  Where is your data stored?  Is the calendar static?

Comment: data is stored in SQL server 2008. The calendar is static just displays the information at the moment.

Comment: How you know It is  a holiday or not ? you specify it in DB. ? Are you pulling dates from DB and showing. ? Do you want to show in date picker or after slecting you just want to validate?

Comment: Sorry. I should have been detailed. I am thinking of giving the user the ability to select a date range OR select a month. The dates are recorded in the database and I am trying to pull in the dates and mark on the calendar when they are off or on vacation.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to output a `<table>`, using something like [SortTable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) or a javascript framework to output it.

Hook up some javascript on the table's click events, and use AJAX to ask PHP for the relevant information. The PHP script can call the database and output the information in something such as JSON.

Without any more specifics in your question I don't think you're going to get much more help.